# Log-in to Jenkins which is visible through HTML frame

Tags: html, jenkins, iframe, devops, http-status-code-403

I am trying to be able to use Jenkins through HTML frame.
So far I was able to see the Jenkins inside the i-frame but I am not able to log-in to the Jenkins.

What I get when trying to log-in is:

```
403 (Forbidden)
```

Is there any way to set Jenkins to be able to work through an i-frame?
(let's assume I don't have any security restrictions).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to integrate Jenkins in your application through i-frame using the xframe filter plugin.

We are using this to enable iframe based integration of jenkins pages in our application

https://plugins.jenkins.io/xframe-filter-plugin/